# Adding security to spring webservice for password

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-security

i am new to spring. i need to make a user registration form where user will provide their basic details and password which i am directly saving to database.password is as string datatype in registration bean and varchar in database.
Now my approach is that i will do the service call from mobile or website to that web service and send password as plain text.
But i think this is not a good way as there is no security while sending data through webservice or in server code or in database, password is just a string with few validations.
Is there a good approach to do this task according to industry standards.
Thank you in advance.

Also i want that my password should not be intercepted by hackers or in server. The password should go in encrypted form from client and should save in database.Nobody managing server/DB should see that password.

Comment: the answer given in the following link might help [Hashing password at client side](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/https-security-should-password-be-hashed-server-side-or-client-side)

Answer (score 0):

Use [BCryptPasswordEncoder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html) provided by Spring Security to encrypt your user's password and store hashed password string to the database.

Example:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public User create(UserCreateForm form) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(form.getEmail());
    user.setPasswordHash(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(form.getPassword()));
    user.setRole(form.getRole());
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```